# jQuery needs to return entire object and not just containing data

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I get jQuery to return the entire

```
<div class="loan_officer_apply_now_link"><a href="">APPLY NOW!</a></div>
```

Currently it only returns the contain "a" element

```
<a href="">APPLY NOW!</a>
```

**Test Code**

```
$('a').click(function(){
    alert($('.loan_officer_apply_now_link').html());
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gUd9J/1/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html

Comment: @Rfvgyhn similar questions but the top solutions for that question are woefully outdated compared to the working answers on this page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the element's [outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.outerHTML) property

```
$('a').click(function(){
    alert($('.loan_officer_apply_now_link').get(0).outerHTML);
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xnmyt/)

Comment: What about the first link?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan which one

Answer (score 5):

Use the native JS `.outerHTML` property instead of just the jQuery `.html()` function. It will make you life a lot easier, instead of trying to do fancy jQuery wraps. You can do this with the following:

```
$(selector)[0].outerHTML // This is your HTML code
```

Comment: I'm guessing you haven't tested this.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan what makes you say that :P

Comment: Yeah, thought for a second jQuery exposed it, but I was wrong. Did a quick ninja edit to fix things up :)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery doesn't have a built-in function for this.. here's one solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/TvWLL/

```
$('a').click(function(){
    alert($('.loan_officer_apply_now_link').clone().wrap('<div>').parent().html());
})
```

Answer (score 0):

give a wrapper class to it

```
<a href="#">Click Me</a><br /><br />
<div class="container">
<div class="loan_officer_apply_now_link"><a href="">APPLY NOW!</a></div>
</div>

$('a').click(function(){
    alert($('.container').html());
})
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gUd9J/3/)

Answer (score 0):

It appears you want the parents html:

```
$(this).parent()[0].outerHTML
```